# cordovaDialogs is showing default text, Not showing custom text

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to show confirm box, which is working fine. But it showing default text, OK, and cancel.

I want to show different text. Also Can we show three buttons as well.

```
$cordovaDialogs.confirm('message', 'title', ['button 1','button 2'])
    .then(function(buttonIndex) {
      // no button = 0, 'OK' = 1, 'Cancel' = 2
      var btnIndex = buttonIndex;
    });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code works for me on Device and Simulator, it is not working on browser.

Comment: see my answer please.

Comment: i have checked .. your answer is also seems fine. But i need to use Cordova dialogs

Comment: Cordova necessarily because you must use dialogue? Using ionic and framework should take what is already done.It is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was developing an app using Ionic v0.9.27 plus ngCordova.

When I ran the app in debug mode the first thing I notice is that cordovaDialogs module in ng-cordova.js was always creating an ordinary confirmation window (and passing to that window only the message) since the code check if **$window.navigator.notification** var is define and when is not the code executed is just **$window.confirm(message)**, the callback is resolve later by the same method.

What I did is install cordova-plugin-dialogs following the documentation for that project, which is basically run cordova cli command like this: **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs**

Then build and deploy the app again to fix the issue. Another thing you can try is within ng-cordova.js file (first, check if you not using the minimize version of the library) harcode the below code and check if the generate popup has everything in place.

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
 navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Test popup',  // message
    onConfirm, 
    'Test window',            // title
     ['Custom button1','Custom button2'] // buttonLabels
);

function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
if(buttonIndex==2){
alert('You selected button - no');
}else{
alert('You selected button - yes');

}

}
```

Since this post is kind of old, I guess the owner of the question probably found a workaround, but I hope this is useful for someone else facing the same problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ionicPopup is comfortable and easy to edit. Visited [ionicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

```
$ionicPopup.show({
     title: 'Test title',
     subTitle: '',
     content: 'test content on pop up',
     buttons: [
       { text: 'No', //Cancel button
        onTap: function(e){
          //function negative
        }
       },
       {
         text: 'Yes', //Ok button
         type: 'button-positive',
         onTap: function(e) {
            //function positive
         }
       },
     ]
    })
```